# Error: Class "CRM_Dkbrapi_APIWrapper_Attachment" not found in dkbrapi_civicrm_apiWrappers()

Tags: drupal, api

This is my first module in CiviCRM and I have the example from the documentation but I can't get it to work. Every time I try to run in CiviCRM API Explorer v3 for attachments I get the following:
Error: Class "CRM_Dkbrapi_APIWrapper_Attachment" not found in dkbrapi_civicrm_apiWrappers() (line 14 of [Drupal 9 Path]\sites\default\files\civicrm\ext\dkbrapi\dkbrapi.php).

-> dkbrapi.php

```
<?php

function dkbrapi_civicrm_apiWrappers(&$wrappers, $apiRequest) {
  if ($apiRequest['entity'] == 'Attachment' && $apiRequest['action'] == 'create') {
    if ($apiRequest['version'] == '3') {
      $wrappers[] = new CRM_Dkbrapi_APIWrapper_Attachment();
    }
  }
}
```

Class file Attachment.php in CRM/Dkbrapi/APIWrapper

```
<?php
class CRM_Dkbrapi_APIWrapper_Attachment implements API_Wrapper {
  public function fromApiInput($apiRequest) {
    // do some stuff

    return $apiRequest;
  }
  public function toApiOutput($apiRequest, $result) {
     return $result;
  }
}
```

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Check that your info.xml has lines like this:

  ```
  <classloader>
    <psr0 prefix="CRM_" path="."/>
    <psr4 prefix="Civi\" path="Civi"/>
  </classloader>
  ```
- Clear civi cache: Administer - system settings - clear caches

Comment: Great, it seems to be working, thanks! I saw this part in the info.yml but didn't realize it needed another classloader.